# return 1 and return 0 VS return true and return false

Tags: php

Me and my colleague were arguing about how to return booleans in PHP functions.

Which one do you use and why?

```
return 0;
return 1;
```

OR

```
return false;
return true;
```

It is clear that first variant it wouldn't work fine in programming languages with strict typing, but it will work absolutely fine in PHP in most cases.

I use first more logical variant, but I couldn't come up with good arguments but "return boolean if you want to return a boolean" and "more readable", but they are quite weak.

Comment: true/false or TRUE/FALSE -- office-wide readability.

Comment: `1 == true`, `true == 1`, `0 == false`, `false == 0` And that's it

Comment: If you want to return true or false, return true or false. What is there to argue about?

Comment: njk, but 1 !== true, and 0 !== false, very important to remember.

Comment: what about [2/file_not_found](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_.aspx)?

Comment: If you've spent time arguing about this, then you've already lost. `true` and `false` exist for a reason. If they're appropriate to your use case, you should use them.

Answer (score 4):

- option with true / false more popular
- harder to get confused in the code
- return Boolean true / false is clear to all, rather than 1/0

Answer (score 1):

For a function that needs to return a boolean, use true/false. Cant go wrong with that. I typically use numerical returns for functions that can return a variety of different things (i.e. -1, 0 or 1 for a tri-conditional function)